# How can I do a conditional variable based on a ID and Year? R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

I am working with a dataset of firms and try to know when they closed or not

So my dataset is like this:

```
Year    ID      Open
2014    a1       Y
2015    a1       Y
2016    a1       Y
2017    a1       Y

2014    a2       Y
2015    a2       N
2016    a2       N
2017    a2       N

2014    a3       Y
2015    a3       N
2016    a3       Y
2017    a3       N
```

And I want to make 3 conditional variables

If it´s opened in 2014 and closed in 2015 its 1, other way 0
If it´s opened in 2014 and closed in 2016 its 1, other way 0
If it´s opened in 2014 and closed in 2017 its 1, other way 0

So my desired dataset is this:

```
Year    ID      Open   C15   C16  C17
2014    a1       Y      -     -    -
2015    a1       Y      0     0    0
2016    a1       Y      0     0    0
2017    a1       Y      0     0    0  #Because firm never closed

2014    a2       Y      -     -    -
2015    a2       N      1     0    0 #Firm def. closed in 2015
2016    a2       N      0     1    0 #Still closed
2017    a2       N      0     0    1 #Still closed

2014    a3       Y      -     -    -
2015    a3       N      1     0    0  #Firm closed this year 
2016    a3       Y      0     0    0  #Firm is open again
2017    a3       N      0     0    1  #Firm closed again
```

The data frame is grouped by ID, but I don´t know how to make the conditional on 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function which gives a 1/0 value based on the conditions.

```
is_open <- function(Open, Year, y1, y2) {
  as.integer(Open[match(y1, Year)] %in% 'Y' & 
             Open[match(y2, Year)] %in% 'N' & Year %in% y2)
}
```

and call it for each `ID` and each `Year` value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(C15 = is_open(Open, Year, 2014, 2015), 
         C16 = is_open(Open, Year, 2014, 2016), 
         C17 = is_open(Open, Year, 2014, 2017)) %>%
  ungroup

#    Year ID    Open    C15   C16   C17
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
# 1  2014 a1    Y         0     0     0
# 2  2015 a1    Y         0     0     0
# 3  2016 a1    Y         0     0     0
# 4  2017 a1    Y         0     0     0
# 5  2014 a2    Y         0     0     0
# 6  2015 a2    N         1     0     0
# 7  2016 a2    N         0     1     0
# 8  2017 a2    N         0     0     1
# 9  2014 a3    Y         0     0     0
#10  2015 a3    N         1     0     0
#11  2016 a3    Y         0     0     0
#12  2017 a3    N         0     0     1
```

If there are many years in the data and you cannot call `is_open` manually for each year we can use `map` :

```
bind_cols(df, purrr::map_dfc(2015:2017, 
             ~df %>% 
                group_by(ID) %>% 
                transmute(!!paste0('C', .x) := is_open(Open, Year, 2014, .x)) %>%
                ungroup %>%
                select(-ID)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2014L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L), ID = c("a1", "a1", 
"a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3"), 
    Open = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", 
    "Y", "N")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Hello, I got this error :(`> Balances2<-Balances2 %>%
+   group_by(RUC) %>%
+   mutate(C15_aps = is_open_aps(APS, Año, 2014, 2015)) %>%
+   ungroup
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `C15_aps`.
x Input `C15_aps` can't be recycled to size 8.
i Input `C15_aps` is `is_open_aps(APS, Año, 2014, 2015)`.
i Input `C15_aps` must be size 8 or 1, not 0.
i The error occurred in group 2: RUC = 190000222001.`)

Comment: I updated the answer to include the data which I am using copied from your post as `dput`. 1) Can you test if my answer works on that data as expected? 2) If it does work on that sample data but does not work on your actual data can you provide your data or subset of data using `dput` in the same way so that I can test my answer?

Comment: You get the same error from the data in my post? That's strange, it works for me without any issues on that data.

Comment: No, same error on my data. The example works, maybe is the fact that in my real data there are a lot of NA?

Comment: Okay...try the updated function `is_open` to handle `NA` values.

Comment: Didn´t worked on my data. I´ll send you my data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229497/discussion-between-jorge-paredes-and-ronak-shah).

Comment: @JorgeParedes I think there is an issue with the column names. Check the chat.